# Change colour of single cell in DataGrid when selected, overriding current colour

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have this code which affects the whole row of a `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="tblopenRequests" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" 
          IsReadOnly="true" RowHeaderWidth="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" SelectionMode="Single">
   <DataGrid.Resources>
      <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" >
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSeaGreen" />
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="white" />
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
         <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1 1 1 1"/>
         <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,-1,0,0" />
         <Setter Property="Height" Value="28" />
         <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto"/>
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
      </Style>
      <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right" />

         <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="Goldenrod" />
               <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="white" />
               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="black" />
               <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
               <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
            </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers>

      </Style>

   </DataGrid.Resources>
```

I now want to make ONE cell in the row be overridden with a different format to stand out more.

This is all I have at the moment but I keep failing in my attempts.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding expectedDate}" Header="Expected Date" Width="90">
   <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
      <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
         <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="center" />
      </Style>
   </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

I have tried adding atrigger in here and colouring the cell only. However, this didn't do anything, just kept the orange from the above code in the resources section.

I just need this one cell pink/light red instead of orange but I can't find a site or forum article with this answer.

Comment: Orange? I have not found Orange in your code/XAML.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Datagrid cell font colour is changing the entire row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23386607/datagrid-cell-font-colour-is-changing-the-entire-row)

Comment: @GlennAngel: You know that the `DataGridColumn` has a `CellStyle` property that you can set to a `Style` for each individual column?

Comment: Thanks @mm8 i will look into that and the answer.  First time ever on WPF so large learning curve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Single Cell Style With Bindings

In your cell style, you can refer to the associated column and identify it e.g. by comparing its `Header`.

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
   <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
      <!-- ...other setters. -->
      <Style.Triggers>
         <!-- ...other triggers. -->
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Expected Date">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink" />
         </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Depending on the state in which the color should be changed, you might need to use a `MultiDataTrigger` for example to change the color only in selected state.

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
   <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
      <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True" />
      <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Expected Date" />
   </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink" />
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

---

Using the `Header` to identify a column is cumbersome and **error prone**. Unfortunately there is no built-in unique identifier on columns that you can use. However, you can create an attached property.

```
public static class DataGridColumnProperties
{
   public static readonly DependencyProperty IdentifierProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Identifier",
      typeof(string), typeof(DataGridColumnProperties), new PropertyMetadata(null));

   public static string GetIdentifier(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
   {
      return (string)dependencyObject.GetValue(IdentifierProperty);
   }

   public static void SetIdentifier(DependencyObject dependencyObject, string value)
   {
      dependencyObject.SetValue(IdentifierProperty, value);
   }
}
```

Using this attached property, you can set an identifier on your column.

```
<DataGridTextColumn local:DataGridColumnProperties.Identifier="ExpectedDate" ...>
```

You would refer to it in the style like this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Column.(local:DataGridColumnProperties.Identifier), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="ExpectedDate">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink" />
</DataTrigger>
```

This approach keeps your column definitions more robust, as styles are independent of the `Header`.

### Multiple Cell Styles

If you prefer to use multiple cell styles, you can solve your issue without bindings. In the following, I have created all styles within the `DataGrid`, but you can move them to any resource dictionary.

Define a regular cell style that applies to most columns, here `RegularCellStyle`. This is the style from your question. Then, create a special style for the first column, here `SpecialCellStyle`.

This style uses the `BasedOn` attribute to inherit all setters and triggers from the regular style. In this style you *only define what changes* compared to the base style. In your case it is only the `Background` in selected state, so we add a trigger for it.

Next, we apply the regular style to the `DataGrid`s [`CellStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.cellstyle?view=netcore-3.1) property. This style will be applied to all columns. Then we apply the special style to the [`CellStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.cellstyle?view=netcore-3.1) of the first column. The column cell style will take precedence. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.cellstyle?view=netcore-3.1#remarks):

> A Style can be applied to a cell at the table, column, or cell level. To apply a Style to all cells in a column, set the DataGridColumn.CellStyle property. This will take precedence over the DataGrid.CellStyle property. To apply a Style to an individual cell, set the Style property directly on the DataGridCell. This will take precedence over all other styles applied to the cell.

Below is the complete code for your sample.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="tblopenRequests" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" 
          IsReadOnly="true" RowHeaderWidth="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" SelectionMode="Single">
   <DataGrid.Resources>

      <!-- Style from your question. -->
      <Style x:Key="RegularCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right" />
         <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="Goldenrod" />
               <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="white" />
               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="black" />
               <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
               <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
            </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>

      <!-- Special first column style based on the regular style. -->
      <Style x:Key="SpecialCellStyle"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource RegularCellStyle}"
                   TargetType="DataGridCell">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink" />
            </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>

   </DataGrid.Resources>
   <DataGrid.CellStyle>
      <StaticResource ResourceKey="RegularCellStyle" />
   </DataGrid.CellStyle>
   <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
      <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSeaGreen" />
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="white" />
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
         <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1" />
         <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,-1,0,0" />
         <Setter Property="Height" Value="28" />
         <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto" />
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
      </Style>
   </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
   <DataGrid.Columns>

      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding expectedDate}"
                          Header="Expected Date"
                          Width="90"
                          CellStyle="{StaticResource SpecialCellStyle}"/>

      <!-- ...other columns WITHOUT cell style will apply the regular style. -->

   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to *@thatguy*. The upper apporach helped me a lot. It's worth to mention that this is one of many answers on stackoverflow and the web which works with  AutoGenerateColumns="True".

Conditional colors can also be done in code behind with:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">                     
                <Style.Triggers>                         
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Expected Date">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding SomeColor}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
  </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

And for example:

```
public SolidColorBrush SomeColor
{
    get
    {
         return IsDifferent ? new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 139, 0)) : new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(139, 255, 139, 0));
    }
 }
```